# MySQL Where clause misinterpreting data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

It is strange for me that for MySQL '1kdasa' AND '1' seem to be the same thing. I ran the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `applications` 
WHERE user_id =  '1dadawdq'
AND uni_id =  '3'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And the result was  a row where user_id = 1. Well this is really strange. I want to check whether user with particular id exists but if MySQL doesn't understand that '1ada' is not '1' I have to write:

```
public function user_exists($user_id){

       if(!is_numeric($user_id)){
           return FALSE;
       }

        $query = $this->CI->db->get_where('user', array('id'=>$value));

        return $query->num_rows() === 1;
}
```

Is this the only possible solution? I don't think it's very smart to check everytime if the passed variables are numeric or not.

**Update**
If i don't escape the data that is :

```
SELECT * FROM `applications` WHERE user_id = eqewq and uni_id = 2
```

There shows up an error :

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'eqewq' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: what is the type of the `user_id` field? if it's an int, then mysql will treat `1dadawdq` as `1`. similarly, `2p3q4r` will get truncated down to `2`.

Comment: That was going to be my guess @MarcB (:

Comment: yes, several times. But.. please take a look at the edit i'll do ...

Comment: You should absolutely you verifying user data every time they submit it. If you are expecting a number, and they submit a string, you shouldn't be running a query at all, but rather giving an error message

Comment: @MarcB The type of field is integer

Comment: Then that begs the question of why you're comparing strings to integers and expecting things to "just work"?

Comment: @Noah I get the idea but does that mean that everytime i need number i have to write if(!is_numeric($param)){return FALSE;} ??

Comment: @user3338547 Your field is `INTEGER` and you use an `eqewq` string to check? How so?

Comment: Generally, you should have a wrapper that handles your request data and returns errors if all of the passed data doesn't match the expected results. I always run type checks and regex matches against received data to ensure I only get exactly the type of data I want.

Comment: @MarcB Well, I know that Codeigniter escapes data. Second, I call this function in a controller body and it is something like that: example.com/controller/method/$param. The $param should be $user_id. I check with the function above in the question whether such user exists since I don't know if someone wants to pass 'dadasd' or '12212ewa' in the URL.

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP or with CI: it's purely MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: code igniter cannot change how mysql operates. you're doing `int = string`, which means mysql will try to convert the string to int so it becomes an `int = int` comparison.

Comment: Well, now i understand how MySQL treats the data. But do you think the solution I showed earlier is right?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1='1';
+-------+
| 1='1' |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+

SELECT 1='1a';
+--------+
| 1='1a' |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+

SELECT '1'='1a';
+----------+
| '1'='1a' |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a string through an int field. This causes MySQL to only parse the first numerical characters. You can try to seacrh for `a1dadawdq` and you will have zero results because the first character is not numeric.
So it is very important you always check your input and prepare your queries before you send it to MySQL. You can try using [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for this.

PDO or MySQLi are not directly a solution to your problem but they can help you since you can use their prepare() method. But verifying your input data will definitely help you. If you only want an integer to be passed through to MySQL try something like:

```
if (!is_int($idUser)) { 
   $idUser = null; 
}
```

Or:

```
if (!is_int($idUser)) { 
   return false; 
}
```

In the case of your update you can use PDO's bindParam() or bindValue() to pass only variables and no query string. By doing so, MySQL will never mistake a value for a column. Read the documentation and see whether you'll prefer PDO or MySQLi.
Personaly I use PDO becasue of the wide support of different database types.

Comment: and how can mysqli or pdo help me?.. hints?... :)

Comment: thank you! I guess that the validation should be in the controller not in the model, right?

Comment: The validation itself should be in the model and should be triggered from the controller.